# Nginx vs Apache & mod_php for PHP and php+fpm vs fastcgi

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, scalability

It seems to be universally recommended to run Nginx as a reverse proxy in front of Apache but there seems to be a devision in opinion on whether Apache + mod_php or Nginx are better for serving dynamic requests and ditto with php+fpm vs fastcgi when using Nginx to serve PHP.

Can anyone offer any good pointers or advice?

Thanks,

Ian

Answer (score 1):

you can use php-fpm instead of fastcgi. I use nginx + php-fpm for my site with about 40 000 visitors and about 1 000 000 pages per day.

Comment: My question was why would you do that though? - what are the advantages of php-fpm over fastcgi?

Comment: @ichilton PHP-FPM *is* fastcgi, it's literally an an acronym of PHP Fastcgi Process Manager. The FPM project was born to fix mistakes in the fastcgi process handling of vanilla PHP. The improvements in stability and features such as the slow log, pools etc is just hugely useful in a lot of situation.